# How many principal component analysis should I conduct for each construct?

Tags: logistic-regression, pca, factor-analysis

I would like to conduct PCA to reduce the number of total 14 items. After getting the principle components, I will use these components as independent variables in a logistic regression.

These 14 items belong to two construct: resources (5 items) and cultural (9 items).

My question is that whether I should conduct one PCA for all 14 items OR two different PCA's for each two constructs and getting the components. At the end, I would like to be able to interpret two different constructs (resources and cultural) separately in the logistic regression output.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Only one PCA should be conducted on all variables. For more detailed interpretation of the analysis, there is need of rotation and subsetting the variables, then using them in the logistic regression. The book below is a good reference:

George H. Dunteman - Principal Components Analysis (1989)